# Under Gnome Shell (17.10 or 18.04), how do I control automatic poweroff on low battery?

Tags: gnome, power-management, shutdown, battery, systemd-logind

I'm unclear on the way automatic actions (eg shutdown) are taken under systemd / gnome shell, and the way o configure them.

How do UPower / systemd-logind / tlp / ??? work together, and how do I set the battery level that will trigger an action ?

Comment: had you found any solution?

Comment: No, nothing until now...